# operations on files in c++

Tags: c++

for example we have  created file in c++  how to write  content in this file and then output on screen?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ Did you GOOGLE at all ?

Comment: "how to write content in this file and then output on screen?" Easy. Just use functions provided by standard library.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=file+reading+c%2B%2B

Comment: Guys , does SO force people to google before using it? let people ask their question

Comment: I'd say SO forces people to make a little effort, in learning the technology, or solving their problem. If people uses Google before asking a question (or consider the *related questions* provided by SO question form), it will save the time, energy of other persons, and by reusing existing answers, will save electrons too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

Writing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Reading:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    while(getline(myfile,line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

You should really use Google.

Answer (score 1):

Read [**this**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) and then come back and ask if you have a more specific question, thanks.

Comment: i have question no one gave me output why?

Comment: Because the question you asked was a very general and to be honest a quite simple question. While we do not demand you spend hours googling for an answer, for something like this a quick google for "c++ write content file" would get you the link I provided in my answer, which is has both code examples and is also a good tutorial on file reading/writing in C++. vtorhonen below actually quoted the examples from that link, so that you don't even have to click on it. If you are still struggling, I can write up an example in my answer for you.